# Yii cGridView Update having Error "TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView is undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii, model

I'm having an error with gridview update

```
TypeError: $.fn.yiiGridView is undefined;
```

after i use AjaxLink

Button Click for Refresh

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#tombol_refresh").click(function(){
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('mdata-pribadi-grid'); 
  });
}); 
</script>
```

AjaxLink

```
<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink(
    'Open New',          // the link body (it will NOT be HTML-encoded.)
    array('mDataPribadi/create'), // the URL for the AJAX request. If empty, it is assumed to be the current URL.
    array(
            'update'=>'#req_res',
    )
);
echo '<div id="req_res">...</div>';
?>
```

Button Refresh

```
<button id="tombol_refresh">Refresh</button>
```

cGridView

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'mdata-pribadi-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'nim',
        'nama',
        'tempat_lahir',
        'tgl_lahir',
        'kode_program_studi',
        'kode_pendidikan_akhir',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

thanks

Fajar

Comment: Thanks for u comment. Where i remove $?

Answer (score 0):

Both jQuery and Yii uses `$`. When you use `$` in a jQuery function, `$` refers to the jQuery script and not Yii's. You will need to unconflict both by using another symbol for jQuery.

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Error if i use like This

jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#refresh").click(function(){
   jQuery.fn.yiiGridView.update('mlantai-grid');
  });
});